# To get the column Index Of gridview after Databind

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

what I have done with a grid view is .. According to ma database i have added columns to the datatable and after that i binded it to a gridview.,

here is the code,

/// Get Activities here to bind to GridView To Get the Activities at first Column.

```
    Dt = BlObj.BlDynamic_Table("[USP_DynamicGridView]", 2);
    DtOperation = BlObj.BlDynamic_Table("[USP_DynamicGridView]", 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < DtOperation.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Dt.Columns.Add(DtOperation.Rows[i][0].ToString());
    }
    dgrDynamic.DataSource = Dt;
    dgrDynamic.DataBind();
```

but for me needed is to get the column index.. here is the code

```
private int GetColumnIndexByName(int p)

{
    return ((int)GetColumnName(BlObj.BlDynamic_Table("[USP_DynamicGridView]", 
    4, p).ToString()));
}

private int GetColumnName(string name)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dgrDynamic.Columns)
    {
        int Index = 0;
        if(col.Equals(name.ToLower().Trim()))
       // if (col.Name.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            return Index;
        }
        Index += 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

What the problem is the foreach loop is not working..

I'm a fresher to .NET and I also don't know whether I have followed the right way.. can anybody please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
private int GetColumnIndex(GridView gv, string columnName, int columnCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
        if (gv.Columns[i].HeaderText == columnName)
            return i - columnCount + 1;
    throw new Exception("no such column '" + columnName + "'");
}
```

It works in my codebase.

Comment: Senior the thing is that am not getting the dgrDynamic.Columns.Count as 0.. why it is so.. and i think thats why foreach loop is not working Properly